# How to change FilterRow language in devextreme-react/data-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devextreme

How can i change devextreme FilterRow ui language. For examle : I want to change "Starts with" text to "New starts with" text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if overriding the `operationDescriptions` config accomplishes what you're trying to achieve?

Check out the docs:
https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/filterRow/operationDescriptions/

```
<DataGrid ... >
            <FilterRow ... >
                <OperationDescriptions
                    startsWith="New starts with"
                />
            </FilterRow>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Than you. It works.

Answer (score 0):

For changing the ui language for all DevExtreme components, check out the [`localization`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Common/Localization/) part of the offical documentation.

Here is an example on how to load a specific language:

```js
// ...
// Dictionaries for German language
import deMessages from "devextreme/localization/messages/de.json";
import { locale, loadMessages } from "devextreme/localization";
  
// ===== React ======
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        loadMessages(deMessages);
        locale(navigator.language);
    }
}
```

Here is a list of all available languages on [GitHub](https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExtreme/tree/22_1/js/localization/messages).

If you only want to change a specific operation text inside the data grid component, [Cătălin Andrei Preda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73624260/7511887) is the correct one.